# Solr query having Frange with complex custom function performance issue

Tags: java, solr, solrj

We are making a solr query where we are giving a custom function (which is pretty complex) and sorting the results by value of that function. The time taken by the query was in the range of 200 to 400 miliseconds. After this we added

`fq:{!frange l=40 u=100}$complexCustomFunction`

so the whole complex query looks like

`solr/select?customFunc=complexFunction(querySpecificValue1,querySpecificValue2)&sort_by=$customFunc&fq={!frange l=40 u=100}$customFunc...`

After adding just this frange fq the time taken for the query has go up ten times, so it takes around 4secs

Answer (score 2):

We just moved the frange from fq to q and that changed the time taken by the query between 200 to 400ms. 
The resulting query now looking something like this:

`customFunc=complexFunction(querySpecificValue1,querySpecificValue2)&sort_by=$customFunc&q={!frange l=40 u=100}$customFunc...`